# How can I prevent quotation marks from being turned into umlauts?

Tags: quoting, german

So I am writing my assignment, and use "" for quotation. However when the quote begins with an A, I, O or U it turns them into Ï, Ä, Ö, Ü. Is there away to avoid this?

Comment: you should not use `"` as an input character in latex, use `\`\``for left and `''`  for right double quotes

Comment: much appreciated!

Comment: Perhaps a better solution for quotations: use the `csquotes` package and its `\enquote` package. That is easier to use if one has a keyboard where `` ` `` is hard to type. Plus then you can change the look of the quotes in the preamble.

Answer (score 1):

There might be another way. David is correct, of course, in pointing out “the one true `LaTeX` way” of doing things, i.e. use `` and `''` respectively. Writing in both German an English a lot myself (and with a German QWERTZ keyboard at that) I have always found this cumbersome to type, particularly the grave accent ` which for me primarily functions as a dead key for accented characters (think àèò etc.)

To simply prevent `Babel` from turning your " marks into umlauts, you can disable shorthands, like so:

```
\usepackage[shorthands=off,english,ngerman]{babel}
```

For the quotation marks itself, I recommend `csquotes`. Here is my setup:

```
\usepackage[autostyle=true, babel=true,
english=american, german=quotes]{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}
```

There are potential issues with nested quotes, `TikZ` etc., but for the most part is just works: You can use "regular" quotes and `Babel` turns them into “typographical” (German: „typographische“) ones automatically (even »Guillemets« if you want to be fancy), obeying the currently active language. (If it comes to the worst, you can always use `\DisableQuotes` and `\EnableQuotes` before and after a troublesome environment, like `tikzpicture`.)

It was a game changer for me.